# Use WebView instead of a UITextField to get benefits of HTML for easier fonts management

Tags: ios, webview

I wondering whether use a webView to create a complex text area done with bold, colors and types would be a good solution or if you consider it a bad one. In that case would you kindly suggest me some alternatives ?

The first problem i get is the impossibility to use multi line label... so if I move to UITextField i can't either use shadows or use more fonts size in the same text.

The only solution that i see is the webView but i'm not sure this is, from a tech point a view, a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep html files in your project and open them in a web-view, phoneGap style! There's nothing wrong with that. But the best way would be to draw your text in your custom label. BTW, `UILabel`s can be multi-line, set no of `yourLabel. numberOfLines =0;` and `yourLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;`